# Massless particle as a result of annihilation of "heavy" particles

Tags: antimatter, photons

How can a massless particle such a photon be the result of electron-positron annihilation? What about the law of conservation of energy? Is a valid explanation that the pair's energy transforms itself into the kinetic energy of the photon, not its mass?

Comment: Just as a general note: *types* of energy are not conserved, only total energy. The first place students usually encounter this is in in-elastic collisions: the kinetic energy of the products is *not* equal to the kinetic energy of the initial bits. There is no apriori reason to think that the *mass* of the reactants needs to be expressed as mass in the products. Now $\sum m_i = \sum m_f$ does hold in day to day life at the human scale, but you're asking about things at a very different size and energy density.

Answer (score 2):

Photons are massless but they do have momentum. Check the relativistic energy-momentum equation: $E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4$. Even when $m=0$ particle can have energy.

Answer (score 0):

The annihilation process is $e^-+e^+\to 2\gamma$. In the rest frame of the system,
the spatial momenta of the particles before and after the event are opposite to each other, but their kinetic energies (the 0-component of the relativistic 4-momentum) add up and all four of them are equal.